# Createvector is undefined p5js

Tags: vector, processing

**UPDATE: Forgot to say, I'm using the p5.js editor. The rest of the sketch works, and loads the image.**

When I run this code in the browser I get 'createVector is undefined'. According to the reference for p5.js I'm using the correct syntax.

Any ideas what is wrong?

```
var img;
var bg = 100;

var velocity = createVector(0,0);
var acceleration = createVector(0,0);

function setup() {
  createCanvas(720, 400);
  img = loadImage("assets/bb8body.png");
}

function keyPressed() {
    if (keyIsPressed === true) {
        if (key === 'd') {
            acceleration++;
            velocity.add(acceleration);

            console.log(vx);
        }
    }
}

function damping(){

}

function draw() {
    keyPressed();
    background(bg);
  image(img, velocity, 0);
  damping();
}
```

Comment: How are you including p5.js? If you remove that calls to `createVector()`, do the other p5.js functions work?

Comment: I'm using the p5js editor, and the scripts are included in head, @KevinWorkman

`<script src="libraries/p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="libraries/p5.dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="sketch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% why, but `createVector()` works in `setup()` (not outside).
Additionally, I've spotted two small errors:

```
acceleration++;
```

This won't work as js doesn't support overloaded operators like c++, but you can use p5.Vector's [add()](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/add) function.
Also, the `vx` variable doesn't exist in the rest of your code.

Here's a modified version of your code using p5.Vector instances, but drawing a small box instead of the image, for testing purposes. You can run the demo bellow:

```js
var img;
var bg = 100;

var velocity;// = createVector(0,0);
var acceleration;// = createVector(0,0);

function setup() {
  createCanvas(720, 400);
  velocity = createVector(0,0);
  acceleration = createVector(0,0);
  //img = loadImage("assets/bb8body.png");
}

function keyPressed() {
    if (keyIsPressed === true) {
        if (key === 'd') {
            //acceleration++;
            acceleration.add(1,1);
            velocity.add(acceleration);

            //console.log(vx);
            console.log(velocity.x);
        }
    }
}

function damping(){

}

function draw() {
    keyPressed();
    background(bg);
    rect(velocity.x,velocity.y,20,20)
  //image(img, velocity, 0);
  damping();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.22/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, that was the snag. Thanks. Also I see that the ++ thing of course won't work on a vector, since it's at least two-dimensional.